# How can I pass the query from mysql to laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

My query in mysql `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age FROM employe where month(birthdate)=month(NOW())`

obtain the birthday of the month plus your age from the date of birth.

In laravel:

```
public function index()

{

    {


     $bird = DB::table('employe')

    ->whereraw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age FROM employe where month(birthdate)=month(NOW())') 

    ->select('employe.*')

    ->get();
    return response()->json(
        $bird->toArray()
    );
```

but it generates me error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS edad FROM employe where month(birthdate)=month(NOW())' at line 1 (SQL: select `employe`.* from `employe` where TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age FROM employe where month(birthdate)=month(NOW()))
```

Comment: You can't use aliases on your where clause (`AS ...`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since you have  `$bird = DB::table('employe')` query builder already knows what table to select `FROM` that is why you don' need  `FROM employe` and `->select('employe.*')`
2. `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age` oart of your query has nothing o do with `WHERE` clause. We need to move that filed to `SELECT` section of query.

   ```
   $bird = DB::table('employe')
       ->select(DB::raw('*, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,birthdate,CURDATE()) AS age') 
       ->whereraw('MONTH(birthdate)=MONTH(NOW())')
       ->get();
   ```